# Print all entries in a json file with specified value content, using jq

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm using jq for the first time.  I have a large json file with entries like the one below.  I would like to print the full content (like below) for all entries where the "`file_name`" contains 197407

```
{
    "license": 5,
    "file_name": "COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg",
    "coco_url": "http://mscoco.org/images/57870",
    "height": 480,
    "width": 640,
    "date_captured": "2013-11-14 16:28:13",
    "flickr_url": "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3153/2970773875_164f0c0b83_z.jpg",
    "id": 57870
}
```

I tried the following, and got the following error:

```
$ cat file1.json | jq -c '.file_name[]  | 
select(.file_name[]|contains("197407"))' 

jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
```

Question2: I would like to “sample” the contents of the file (it contains multiple formats of content), perhaps by printing every 1,000th entry.  Can `jq` do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file contains an array of the model you posted, you can match your records with :

```
cat file1.json | jq '.[] | select(.file_name | contains("197407"))'
```

In your statement `.file_name[]` means that you want to return each element of the array `file_name`

Answer (score 0):

Re: Q2

For efficiency, along the lines suggested by Jeff:

```
.[range(0;length;1000)]
```

Or for fun:

```
recurse(.[1000:]; . !=  []) | .[0]
```

Comment: Hmm, I would opt for this instead: `.[range(1000;length;1000)]`. Arrays seem to be implemented as a contiguous block of memory and not a linked list. So I'd imagine creating slices of potentially long lengths wouldn't perform as well.

Comment: Jeff - The fact that arrays are implemented as contiguous blocks of memory really has no bearing on whether the approach using recurse and .[n:] is optimized.  As you know, `recurse` is indeed optimized (TCO), and based on time measurements using jq 1.5, it is clear that .[n:] is also handled efficiently. In fact, the two approaches yield virtually indistinguishable u+s numbers for the cases I've checked so far.

Comment: My initial thought was that slices create new array instances with deep copies of the values. I don't know how far the optimizations go, I'd have to look at the source more closely.  But either way, optimizations or not, indexing should trump any operation.

Comment: Looking back at my earlier comment, if the arrays shared the same memory for the data it wouldn't matter how it was represented. But prior to realizing that, I figured that if it was a linked list, then getting the tail of the array could be obtained relatively easily.